# DSolve Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[$Failed,balancefail] returned to top level. error in 11.2

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, symbolic

Reported also to WRI. [CASE:**3965533**]

---

I am in the process of updating [Kamke differentional equations](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/kamek/kamke_differential_equations.htm) tests for 11.2 when encountered a new error I have not seen before on one of the Kamke ODE's (number 1586 in the Kamke book).

Could someone explain why this comes up now? Is this a new bug or a known issue?

```
ClearAll[y,x,A,a];
n=5;
ode=x*D[y[x],{x,n}]-(a*A[1]-A[0])*x-A[1]-((a*A[2]-A[1])*x+A[2])*
  y'[x]-((a*A[3]-A[2])*x+A[3])*y''[x]-((a*A[4]-A[3])*x+A[4])*
  y'''[x]-((a*A[5]-A[4])*x+A[5])*y''''[x]==0;

DSolve[ode,y[x],x]
```

Which gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

No such message is generated in 11.1

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is on windows 7, home edition. 64 bit.

Comment: Works fine on `11.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit)`